# Grafana with mongodb query for getting unique values by grouping two columns

Tags: grafana

I have mongodb collection in which I have stored test feature name and test name as follows:
|Test Feature | Test Name|
|feature 1    | tes1     |
|feature 1    | test2    |
|feature 2    | test 1   |
|feature 2    | test2    |

so I want to show this data as bar diagram in grafana. So i have written mongodb query with as:

```
db.collections.aggregate([
{$group: {_id:{feature:"$test feature", test:"$test name"}}}
])
```

But this is not working in grafana.
Can anyone please let me know which grafana query/transformation can be used to present bar diagram with unique count of total test name have been executed??